# insert multi array to database in loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array, insert

i have below array

```
Array
(
  [user_id] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 1
        [3] => 1
    )

  [menu_id] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 1
        [3] => 1
    )

 [submenu_id] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 3
        [3] => 4
    )

  )
```

my MySQL Database is like below :

```
user_id | menu_id | submenu_id
        |         |
```

i want to insert above array to my database like below :

```
user_id | menu_id | submenu_id
    1   |   1     |  1
    1   |   1     |  2
    1   |   1     |  3
    1   |   1     |  4
```

how can i insert data like above ? Thank you.

Comment: Well you start by writing some code. If you have problems, then ask a question here and we would love to help. But **SO != free coding resouce**

Comment: `insert multi array to database in loop`. Don't ever insert in a loop.

Comment: have you tried any way of solving it? ex a for loop (nested one)???

Comment: **Hint**: Use Andrew's comment with `$arr['user_id'][0],$arr['menu_id'][0],$arr['submenu_id'][0],.......`

Comment: @Andrew Why not, just out of interest?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'm assuming he's talking about some form on PHP loop here not [mysql loop](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/loop.html). I know you know why not, but I'll humor you anyway. For a few items, it's fine, I've done, everybody has. The problem arises when you try to insert a stupid amount of values. It's not very efficient, hogs a lot of resources and it's simpler to just insert all of them in one go.

Comment: @Andrew You give me too much credit! I asked because I didn't agree, but wanted to know if I had missed something. Not that I can remember adding a stupid amount of rows in a loop before. How does it _hog a lot of resources?_

Comment: @RiggsFolly Depending on how many connections are running that specific script even 10 could be enough. If 100 users visited that page each would make 10 queries, it adds up. Since PHP is well known for being able to run on a rusty bucket, mysql may `has gone away` and nobody wants that.

Comment: @Andrew _Rusty Bucket_ :) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have the same index for on each array you want to get first value from first array(`user_id`) and first from second (`menu_id`) and so on and add it to a row in mysql.

You will need something like this:

```
foreach($data['user_id'] as $key => $user_id){
    //You have $user_id
    $menu_id = $data['menu_id'][$key];
    $submenu_id = $data['submenu_id'][$key];
    //All of this 3 variables you need now to insert to mysql. Try it and let me know WITH code if something is not working like this.
}
```

Comment: You can be too smart, but let the OP try first and come up with a solution.

Comment: This is working, thank you. :)